# How to keep iPhone screen from reducing backlight..?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

My app shows a picture and then an mp3 plays over it, describing the picture. The trouble is that the backlight on the screen reduces after 40 seconds or so, if the phone is not interacted with. How do I prevent the fade?...so that my picture doesn't go dark when they are looking at it.

Comment: Perhaps instruct the user to change his/her backlight settings to use your app?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setIdleTimerDisabled:YES];
```

Comment: Yes, but don't forget to enable the idle timer after your mp3 is done, if left unattended the battery will run down.

Answer (score 1):

Set `UIApplication`'s `idleTimerDisabled` property to `YES`.

Answer (score 0):

For swift the code will be:

`UIApplication.sharedApplication().idleTimerDisabled = true`